# Echo JavaScript variable in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I want to jump the page based on input in php using javascript.

I am trying this but failed.

```
<?php 
   echo '<input type="number" name=“inputID” id=“inputID” ></input>';
   
   // Here I am failed not able to get the input value and jump to the page

   echo "<a href = 'demo-page.php?&page=+document.getElementById('inputID').value'>Jump</a>";

  ?>
```

Kindly suggest what I am doing wrong.

Also is this approach jump to the page is right or wrong?

Any idea or suggestion would be welcome.

Comment: `“` < those curly quotes if that is what you're really using, are causing a parse error.

Comment: Replace the `“` with `"` and try again. If that's all this is, then there's a duplicate for this.

Comment: `'demo-page.php?&page=+document.getElementById('inputID').value'` < That won't execute `document.getElementById('inputID').value` as javascript. It will be read as literal text and will be a part of the URL. Even if it were to be executed as javascript, it would do it on page load, before the user have a chance to enter anything into the input.

Comment: I replaced but still giving error.   echo '<a href = "demo-page.php?&page='+document.getElementById('inputID').value;'">Jump</a>';

Comment: `?&` < is a syntax error. The ampersand is for additional data; remove it.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson  So what is the good practice sir? How to tackle this problem, kindly suggest.

Comment: Btw, your input has no value. Unsure what you want to do here and where the data is coming from.

Comment: I would add a click event on the link (using javascript), where I then get the value from the input and append it to the URL before redirecting the client to the URL.

Comment: You should go and have a good, thorough read of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13840429/what-is-the-difference-between-client-side-and-server-side-programming first of all. The code you have shown clearly shows that you have not understood some very important basics yet.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner I have removed ?& but still giving me the error. The value is blank because user input the page number and when it click on the jump then the page redirect there. I think instead of href I have also used onclick function but failed.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of a field when you click the link, then you need to execute a javascript code when the onclick event fires in the link. The href property does not fires javascript.

So the solution would be:

```
echo '<a href="#" onClick="window.location = \'demo-page.php?&page=\' + document.getElementById(\'inputID\').value + \'">Jump</a>';
```

This will result in the following html code:

```
<a href="#" onClick="window.location = 'demo-page.php?&page=' + document.getElementById('inputID').value + '">Jump</a>
```

Be carefull with quotes!